# How to separate the XML response and extract the embedded attachment

Tags: java, attachment, mime

We receive response from API with embedded attachment. The xml response contains a decryption key to decrypt the attachment which will be the output.

The question as in the title, how can I separate the xml response and the attachment the proper way? Please help.

sample

```
--d61c9671-5b77-4fad-b021-1580c310b717
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/><dsig:KeyInfo xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><xenc:EncryptedKey Recipient="name:55bb96ec-fae4-41ee-9312-d01baf5c5c01"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/><dsig:KeyInfo><dsig:KeyName>55bb96ec-fae4-41ee-9312-d01baf5c5c01</dsig:KeyName></dsig:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>fC8l6LLmJGHBwpdq....</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedKey></dsig:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>QNb6/ODc9g/AMPPIts0aqey....</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData>
--d61c9671-5b77-4fad-b021-1580c310b717
Content-ID: <attachment>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

�î
a´F MmÆ1%@Æ%èðíù7:ºß���-M0dã    ;äÖ=ô¯hÍÁ<<b-·-�`ðàaOIÐËË¨,�}Hd�÷ßD�;x Ö=�Å[�¾�Rxáaã§:¬jYÓ�S%2ÂÂ;ö¢2�*CÄ9íqB_Þ@�fIÇWá¹6AòRO»z[àlW%s�¾Ä�6�ª<i0¡:¤ rLC�ª^¬Ð�]�ów?=ë»+¬%ÐI_·­±U#ô=�}OH�Æ 0rl��Ç��¤�k+0¨HzÄ
--d61c9671-5b77-4fad-b021-1580c310b717--
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.